# Android Paging 3 Adapter scroll to the target position in the next page from other view

Tags: android, android-livedata, coroutine

I have 2 activities: List Item and Detail item.

- List item using Paging 3 to display list item. When click an item it direct to Detail item in other activity.
- Detail item using ViewPager to view detail and it can swipe left/right to view next/pre item(item list same with the list in item view).

The problem is:

- When start to view detail, we send a list item (loaded item page) Ex: 30 item ~ 3 page. But, when swipe to the end list that sent from list, I need load next page to continue display detail. and when back from that next page (ex: item 35 - page 4) to the list item, I have to scroll to the target item (item 35).

Please help me to handle load next page (page 4) and scroll the list to the target item (item 35). I know paging 3 adapter using LiveData so it could not trigger load next page if the list item in the background.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you need to use two activities? You can use a single activity with two fragments and use a shared activity viewmodel between the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is that both activity observes changes on the same data source.

Because you are using Paging 3 you can use room database as your data source.

With Paging 3 and Room extensions you can observe the changes and implement a remote mediator to load more data.

For a complete implementation and to get you started please refer to the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db) that fits your case.

Comment: Thanks Sovathna Hong, 
Remote Mediator is a good way to implement this case. Are there any way to control this case. Because I don't care to save the cache data, does using Room db have more impact to the performance?

Comment: @HocTranT. Yes, of course you can implement it without using Room. But you still need to implement your own `PagingSource`. You can use RxJava or Kotlin Coroutines to implement a `PagingSource`. And to shared the same `PagingSource` for both activities, you need to create a `PagingData` from this `PagingSource` in app scope, so that both activity can use this shared `PagingData`. You can read the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data) in full because it fits your use case perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

But the list item using `PagingDataAdapter` and the Detail activity use `FragmentStateAdapter` with `ViewPager2`. Could I implement adapter for `ViewPager2` like `PagingDataAdapter` to use and trigger next/pre page when swipe left/right?